# Why does my code to write to the sdcard work on one device but not on another device..?

Tags: android

Here is my code: The file never gets created on the SDCARD

```
if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
{
  logger.info("There is no external SD card mounted...stopping application");
  Toast.makeText(MonitorService.this, "There is no external SD card mounted...stopping application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  return;
}

final File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
final File binaryfile = new File(root, "test.log");

      writer = new FileWriter(binaryfile, true);
      out = new BufferedWriter(writer);

      if (root.canWrite())
      {
         System.out.println("I do see this in the logs....");
         out.write("This is a test");
         out.write("\n");
         out.close();
         writer.close();
      }
```

Comment: So, nothing in logcat on the device on which this code fails?  Other than your println(), of course...

Comment: does the file get created if you disconnected the device from PC?

Answer (score 2):

The sdcard write only works if it is NOT mounted on the computer: is one of the devices automatically mounting the SD card? I've seen some of the vendor add-on services that automount the SD card. In general I'd expect `root.canWrite()` to work correctly, but you may want to use [getExternalStorageState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) to verify that the SD card is indeed available.

Comment: I have both devices connected when running this test. The one device works just fine (while connected to PC)...the other device the file is never created. it is the same code. I see no errors in logcat. I am just wondering WHY this isn't working the same on both devices.

Comment: I still get the same result if I unplug the device from the pc and try the code. Not sure why this is happening. I figured that I would post my code because I figured that I might have been doing something wrong.

Comment: Odd question, but if you swap the SD cards do you still have the same problem?

Comment: I also tried adding the if statement above....and it never returns. So it must be mounting the card properly. I also tried swapping the cards but that made NO difference. Does anybody have any other suggestions / thoughts on why this doesn't work on my other device..??